# Python load_source import not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not a proficient Python coder, hence this might be a basic question:

In my main python code, I load a python code file using (dynamically)

```
import imp
model = imp.load_source('name','c:/modeldir/modelfile.py')
```

modelfile.py does an import on the top:

```
from MyLib import MyLib
```

MyLib.py is in the same folder as modelfile.py

I get:

> ImportError: No module named 'MyLib'

I have also tried:

```
import os
os.chdir('c:/modeldir')
```

just before the imp.load_source, did not help.

EDIT:

- I am using Python 3.5.2
- I've added an empty `__init__.py` file in 'c:/modeldir'

How to solve this?

Comment: do you have an `__init__.py` file in your directory ?

Comment: no, no such file...should I have it?

Comment: Yes, by all means! [Take a look at this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

Comment: I added an empty `__init__.py` file...but did not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following made it work

```
sys.path.append('c:/modeldir')
```

This adds the folder to the python import path and then `MyLib` can be found